# Can't seem to add percentage at last in this list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
la = [3, 7, 8, 9, 50, 100]
```

I am trying to convert the list into string and add percentage like this:

```
3%, 7%, 8% and lastly 100%
```

I doing like this:

```
str1 = '%, '.join(str(e) for e in sorted_list)
```

It does the right thing except there's no percentage at last i.e only 100 but I want 100%. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: That's how every sane `join` works. The separator only appears between elements, not before or after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thy this:

```
print map(lambda n: str(n) + '%', [3, 7, 8, 9, 50, 100])
```

Which creates a list of all of them converted to strings with a percent.

If you still want a string, you can slightly modify it like this:

```
str1 = ', '.join(map(lambda n: str(n) + '%', [3, 7, 8, 9, 50, 100]))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
', '.join('%d%%' % (x,) for x in la)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yup, it's doing exactly what it's supposed to: putting '%, ' *BETWEEN* each element.  How about simply ...

```
str1 = '%, '.join(str(e) for e in sorted_list) + '%'
```

(if `sorted_list` can ever be empty, you should handle that case)

Answer (score 1):

```
la = [3, 7, 8, 9, 50, 100]
(lambda k: ' and lastly '.join([', '.join(k[:-1]), k[-1]]))(["%s%%" % a for a in la])
# '3%, 7%, 8%, 9%, 50% and lastly 100%'
```

EDIT: small subscripting mistake (then again, as Rohit Jain says... :D )

Comment: lol.. That is why OP should always give exact output required.

Answer (score 0):

```
python 3.2
str1 = ','.join(str(e)+"%" for e in sorted_list)
```